# java.lang.RuntimeException: Main thread loop unexpectedly exited, what could be the reason?

Tags: java, android

I am implementing simple thread that passes messages to main UI thread to make changes in UL but sometimes I get this exception and can't figure out its exact reason.

```
01-22 21:03:50.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 21:03:50.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18076): java.lang.RuntimeException: Main thread loop unexpectedly exited
01-22 21:03:50.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4426)
01-22 21:03:50.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 21:03:50.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 21:03:50.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-22 21:03:50.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-22 21:03:50.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: { what=102 when=-14h26m28s942ms obj=android.os.BinderProxy@41347e18 } This message is already in use.
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:187)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.queueOrSendMessage(ActivityThread.java:1834)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$200(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.schedulePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:505)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:78)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
01-22 21:03:50.109: E/JavaBinder(18076):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: The log says that you are trying to reuse a Message object. Don't do that; get a fresh Message object for each message. If you can't figure it out, please post your code that is sending messages.

Comment: Yes, I was using same message object. Thnxs :) Please post your answer so that I can mark it as working one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ted  Hopp said:

The log says that you are trying to reuse a Message object. Don't do that; get a fresh Message object for each message.

SO, using fresh messages fixed my problem. As he didn't post his answer even after I asked him to do so, so that I can accept his answer.

So I am doing it by myself.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Sending a same message object **twice or more than once** may also cause the problem. So take a look at your code and check the issue. Mine was the reason.